# Can I filter on a SemiStructured node in Neo4 Model?

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

I am using the Neomodel Python package with the Neo4j database and loving it.  I am currently using the filter() method, but every time I use the filter() method on a property not defined in the  SemiStructuredNode I get an error.

In the example below I have my Person SemiStructuredNode with only surname as a property, but some nodes in the database might have eye_colour as well and I want to filter by that.  Note that not all nodes will have eye colour.

```
class Person(SemiStructuredNode):
    surname = StringProperty()

Person.nodes.filter(surname__contains='atts',eye_colour='BLUE')
```

To me the code above should work but I get a `ValueError: No such property eye_colour on Person` error.  However, if I change my class definition to include eye_colour as a StringProperty everything is fine.  However, I do not want to do this because there are various other dynamic filters I want to use because of different data being imported into the system.

Does Neomodel support what I'm trying to do or will I have to build a Cypher query or can someone see what I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a try and except clause when dealing with this kind of exception.

```
try:
    Person.nodes.filter(surname__contains='atts',eye_colour='BLUE')
except:
    print ("Couldn't filter surname and eye_colour")
```

Comment: Catching the exception isn't an issue, I omitted my exception code on purpose.  The issue is does the SemiStructuredNode support filtering on dynamic properties?